# Unique number at insert depending on other columns

Tags: sql-server, jpa, eclipselink

Suppose I have following table structure

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fy_id", referencedColumnName = "fy_id")
private FYModel fyId;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "branch_id", referencedColumnName = "branch_id")
private BranchModel branchId;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "division_id", referencedColumnName = "division_id")
private DivisionModel divisionId;

@Column(name = "tix_no")
private int tixNo;
```

So, what I would like to happen is for `tix_no` to be generated automatically at insert where it is increased by one starting at 1. `tix_no` can repeat when the combination of `fy_id`, `branch_id`, and `division_id` is unique.

For example;

```
| id | fy_id | branch_id | division_id | tix_no |
| 1  | 1     | 1         | 1           | 1      |
| 2  | 1     | 1         | 1           | 2      | 
| 3  | 1     | 1         | 2           | 1      |
| 4  | 1     | 1         | 3           | 1      |
| 5  | 1     | 2         | 1           | 1      |
| 6  | 2     | 1         | 1           | 1      |
| 7  | 2     | 1         | 1           | 2      |
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know jpa or eclipselink so i am not sure how you want this solved exactly. I am sorry if my answer is note relevant. But from a database perspective i would probably use a trigger. (https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-create-trigger/) Then you can just ignore tix_no and when you make an insert the trigger will execute and there you could find out which value it should have an just set it before the data is saved to the table.

Comment: I agree with @MrApnea, use trigger(s) to calculate and persist the tix_no value. From what little I know of EclipseLink, though, it doesn't support calculated/computed columns which would be essentially how you'd need to treat tix_no so that EclipseLink doesn't write to it.

Comment: Oh, okay, thank for your suggestion. I guess I will try to do it using trigger. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

EclipseLink has [@ReturnInsert](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_returninsert.htm#CIHHEGJE) but the description states it will require using a stored procedure for non-oracle databases so that it can get the returned value to update the cache. EclipseLink can be configured to use your stored procedure for inserts using a [DescriptorCustomizer](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CRUDStoredProcedures)

Using the ReturnInsert annotation is more efficient as EclipseLink will pull the value and so allow keeping the cache in synch with the database - but, you could avoid the need by refreshing the object after the transaction commits.